# Why Arithmetic Exception is an unchecked exception?

Tags: java

Can someone explain why arithmetic exception comes under unchecked exception category?I have searched for it, but no correct answers available.Would be thankful if someone would answer it.

Comment: I would guess something like how would the compiler know you're going to attempt to divide by 0, for example.

Comment: javadoc: "...exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine" - integer division, for example, is probably considered a normal operation of the JVM since not done in a classic method

Answer (score 5):

`ArithmeticException` extends `RunttimeException`, therefore it's unchecked.

Why this design decision? If `ArithmeticException` was checked, then you would have to encapsulate every (!) integer division in `try catch` or add a `throws` to the surrounding method.

The following program wouldn't compile:

```
class MyClass {
    int i = 10;
    void myMethod() {
        int j = 1 / i;
        // do something with j
    }
}
```

You would have to write either

```
void myMethod() throws ArithmeticException {
    int j = 1 / i;
    // do something with j
}
```

or

```
void myMethod() {
    int j;
    try {
        j = 1 / i;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        j = ...; // what value should be used?
    }
    // do something with j
}
```

At least to me, that would be very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

To free developers of dealing with the sorts of exceptions that occur as a result of programming errors such as falling off the end of an array, dividing by zero, and so on some exceptions are nominated as unchecked exceptions (those that derive from `RuntimeException`) and do not need to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's akin to an illegal argument exception.

All of `IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException` and `NullPointerException` are seen as programming errors and unchecked to avoid the excessive proliferation of `throws` clauses throughout code that in principle might throw any and all of those exceptions they're unchecked.

There's only a syntatic difference between:

```
y=a/b;
```

And

```
y=div(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a old thread, but in case it helps, here are some detailed thoughts on the topic with more insights, reasoning & API references. [FAQ about checked exception and unchecked exception?](http://itsallbinary.com/faq-about-checked-exception-and-unchecked-exception/#arithunchecked)

Hopefully this will answer in more depth.